# Log4j2 configuration location

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I am using a Spring boot app with log4j logging enabled.
All is well when I run my Spring boot app, I see the log lines in the correct layout. However, when I run a test, I get:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (be.delijn.ritsimulator.util.LoadTimeTest).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

I have tried moving the log4j2.xml file to every possible place on the classpath but I cannot seem to resolve this issue. I placed it in the root, under resources etc.
I just want to be able to have 1 log4j2.xml file instead of one for main and one for test.
Also, I do not want to set it using the system property.

Is this possible?
If so, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Comment: how do you run your tests?

Comment: Via Intellij > Run Test (Ctrl + Shift + F10)

Comment: you do not override any vm arguments? what tests are you running? any special configurations for tests?

Comment: I do not have any VM arguments set. The tests are plain old jUnit tests that do not have any special configuration.

Comment: your tests under src/test?

Comment: yes it is located there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning you are seeing is a Log4j 1.2 warning. Somewhere in your classpath there’s a log4j-1.2.x.jar that gets loaded before the Log4j2 jars. This is not good.

Please remove the log4j-1.2.x.jar and add the log4j-1.2-api-2.x.jar: this is a compatibility jar that will route log4j 1.2 API calls to the Log4j2 implementation.